# Hide/Unhide NavigationItem SearchController when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I've been at this for 2 days now, and I can't get my UISearchController/NavigationItem to work like it's supposed to **(be hidden at launch, show after scrolling up, hide after scrolling down)**. It's so simple and apparently everyone but me can do it. Here's what I want it to look like: http://blog.eppz.eu/swiftui-search-bar-in-the-navigation-bar/

It's really frustrating and I just want to know if someone out there can guide me through it or direct me to a template file I can download and migrate over to my app.

Here's my viewDidLoad right now, but I've tried it with different UISearchController combinations as well and it didn't work like I wanted:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're adding the searchBar on the tableHeaderView.

This doesn't look good to me: `tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar`

Remove that line and test again.

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if navigationItem.searchController == nil {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
}
```

Comment: That line is what hides the navigationItem.searchBar at launch.

Comment: Ah, got it! If you want it initially hidden at launch, instead of setting the searchController in the viewDidLoad. Set the searchController in the viewDidLayoutSubviews. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Oh, cool! I like this option a lot better. For me it still doesn't hide after the initial scroll though, do you know why that is?